# How to print list of lists in user provided number of columns?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list of lists like this:

```
dictlist=[['A', '0.0'], ['B', '0.0'], ['C', '10.12'], ['D', '0.0'], ['E', '0.0'], ['F', '0.0'], ['G', '2.15'], ['H', '0.0'], ['I', '0.0'], ['J', '0.0'], ['K', '0.0'], ['L', '0.0']]
```

What I wish is to have the list printed in user provided number of columns like this (user provided columns = 5)

```
A   0.0    B  0.0      C  10.12     D   0.0    E   0.0
F   0.0    G  2.15     H  0.0       I   0.0    J   0.0
K   0.0    L  0.0
```

Notice that all values should be tab separated. The idea is to have this in a text file so that it could be easily pasted in excel sheet.

I have tried this, but it is not helping:

```
for i in range(1,len(dictlist)):
    if i % 5 == 0 :
        print "\t".join(dictlist[i]),
        print "\n"
    else:
        print "\t".join(dictlist[i]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python functionality which allows you to print in the same line:

**For 2.7**

```
print("item"), 
print("item")
```

**For 3**

```
print("item",end=" ")
print(item)
```

I have edited the code for you by simply adding a comma after the print statement I want to continue on the same line.

```
for i in range(0,len(dictlist)):
if i % 5 == 0 and i!=0:
    print ("\n")
    print ("\t".join(dictlist[i])),
    print("\t"),
else:
    print ("\t".join(dictlist[i])),
    print("\t"),
```

Comment: thanks, but this produces an extra blank new line after each row. how to remove that

Comment: just add a comma after print("\n") statement. Also remove the and i!=0. Wrote that accidentally